Show that $\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n=\log X+O(1)$ for $X\geq1$
Attempt:
Since $1/ t$ is decreasing, we have its maximum on $[n,n+1]$ and minimum on $[n-1,n]$ is at $t=n$, thus we get $\frac{1}{t} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ $\forall t \in [n,n+1]$ and $\frac{1}{t} \geq \frac{1}{n}$ $\forall t \in [n-1,n]$. Then integrating and combining:
$$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dt}t\leq\frac1n\leq\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dt}t.$$

Now apply sum $\sum_{n=2}^X$ to BHS:
$\sum_{n=2}^X \frac{1}{n} \leq \sum_{n=2}^X \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dt}{t}$. Observe that $\sum_{n=2}^X \int_{n-1}^n \frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^X \frac{dt}{t}$, thus $\sum_{n=2}^X \frac{1}{n} \leq \int_1^X \frac{dt}{t}$. Applying $+1$ to BHS:  $\sum_{n=1}^X \frac{1}{n} \leq 1+ \int_1^X \frac{dt}{t}$

Now applying sum $\sum_{n=1}^{X-1}$ to BHS: $\sum_{n=1}^{X-1} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{X-1} \frac{1}{n}$. Observe that $\sum_{n=1}^{X-1} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^X \frac{dt}{t}$, thus $\int_1^X \frac{dt}{t} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{X-1} \frac{1}{n}$. Adding $+\frac{1}{X}$ to BHS: $\int_1^X \frac{dt}{t} + \frac{1}{X} \leq \sum_{n=1}^X \frac{1}{n}$.


Now combining all we get: $$\log X+\frac1X=\int_1^X\frac{dt}t+\frac1X\leq\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n\leq1+\int_1^X\frac{dt}t=1+\log X.$$
Here I am stuck, not really sure about it.
My questions:

Is this good so far or needs more justification?
I am not really sure why $\sum_{n=2}^X\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dt}t=\int_1^X\frac{dt}t$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{X-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac {dt}{t}=\int_1^X\frac{dt}t$
What do I do after $\log X+\frac1X=\int_1^X\frac{dt}t+\frac1X\leq\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n\leq1+\int_1^X\frac{dt}t=1+\log X?$ I was told to rearrange it and get $|\sum_{n\leq X}\frac1n-\log X|\leq1$ but I don't see it yet somehow


For $(2),$ these are just a generalization of $$\int_a^b f+\int_b^c f=\int_a^c f.$$ We break up the interval $[1,X]$ into intervals $[k,k+1]$ for integers $k.$

For (3), since you already have: $0<\frac{1}{X}\leq \sum_{n\leq X}\frac{1}{n}-\log X\leq 1$ , then $\left\lvert \sum_{n\leq X}^{}\frac{1}{n}-\log X\right\rvert$ is bounded by $1$ therefore $\mathcal{O}(1)$ .

@Ning Maybe I am missing something in my understanding but how does $\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{1}{n}-\log X\leq1$ $\implies |\sum_{n\leq X}\frac1n-\log X|\leq1$? Don't we need $-1 \leq\sum_{n\leq X}{\frac{1}{n}}-\log X\leq1$ for this implication to hold?

@ThomasAndrews Thanks, but I don't really see it yet how those different sums just give rise to the same integral (if you get what I mean)

@Arbatus Note the above left hand size inequation: $-1<0<\frac{1}{X}<\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{1}{n}-\log X$ (and you already derive it in your post actually), that's what you need. By the way $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}-\log n$ is Euler constant, you may find more solutions approaching this problem.

Your approach is correct for proving
$$\log X+\frac1X\leq\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n\leq1+\log X.$$
Now define $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n-\log X$ and easily prove $\limsup_{x\to \infty} f(X)=1$.
A rephrasing of your approach is based on Euler's summation formula which proves a stronger version of your question:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^X\frac1n=\log X+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{X}\right),
$$
where $\gamma=\int_1^\infty\frac{\{x\}}{x^2}dx$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
